# How can voice search improve recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, google-voice-actions

I understand that Google will store the things I say and is supposed to improve recognition of my voice on my android phone.  How can it do this if there is no way to correct it?  I say a persons name several times and it incorrectly recognizes it the same way each time.

How is it going to improve and recognize what I say correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Can I train Google Voice Actions to better recognize my voice?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14168/can-i-train-google-voice-actions-to-better-recognize-my-voice)

Digging around Android forums and elsewhere, I found a good number of testimonies from speech-to-text enthusiasts who saw better results from simply speaking at a normal clip. Google representative Nadja Blagojevic offered much the same advice for the search giant's voice product in both Android and its Chrome browser: "Speak naturally and clearly, but don't strain to enunciate too much or speak slowly."

http://lifehacker.com/5825965/speak-faster-to-improve-voice-recognition-apps

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630707

[image]