# How can I train voice recognition on ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, voice-recognition

Is it possible to train Android's speech recognition?  I have read [Can I train Google Voice Actions to better recognize my voice?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14168/can-i-train-google-voice-actions-to-better-recognize-my-voice) which suggests that there is a setting in the voice search app but I'm running ICS and don't even have a dedicated voice search app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting should still exist, it's just a little bit more awkward to get to. The easiest way is to hit the microphone icon on the search widget (though I think anywhere it appears will work) to bring up the voice action dialog. There's a wrench in the top right of that dialog that opens the settings:

[image]

Tap that to open the settings page, which should have the checkbox titled "Personalized recognition" as in previous versions (tested on a Galaxy Nexus running CyanogenMod 9, Android 4.0.4).

Comment: I've found the menu but the only settings that I have there are "Language", "SafeSearch" and "Block offensive words". This is on a Xperia Neo V, stock. (Android 4.0.2 IIRC).

Comment: @Erik: Do you live outside the US or have your language set to something other than en-US? I believe that's the only supported language currently: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/websearch/TBCC0vCcb7c/bcCv_7uefOYJ

Comment: Both, in fact. Is there any way to work around the location restriction?

Comment: @Erik: That I don't know, unfortunately. You'd *might* be able to get away with installing an en-US ROM, but I'd assume that would be undesirable anyway (and may have other issues, for all I know).